# Angularjs Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting this error:

```
Failed to instantiate module ufyApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

I have had this error before when I started with AngularJS, but haven't made this mistake in a long time.
Not sure why I am getting it, so I hope you guys (or girls) could help me out here.

my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/">
    <title>Unify Taskforce</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="ufyApp">
    <div class="container">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Load Angular libs -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <!-- load Ufy app -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my app.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ufyApp', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'ui.router',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ufyApp.services',
  'ufyApp.controllers',
])
.value('FIREBASE_URL', 'https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/')
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('list', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
        })
        ;
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
.run();
```

my services.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ufyApp.services', ['firebase'])
.factory('Data', ['FIREBASE_URL', function (FIREBASE_URL) {
    return new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
} ])
.factory('Ticket', ['$firebaseArray', 'Data', function($firebaseArray, Data){
    return new $firebaseArray(Data.child('tickets'));
}]);
```

my controllers.js file:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ufyApp.controllers', [])
.controller('TicketController', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$uibModal', 'Ticket', function ($scope, $firebaseArray, $uibModal, Ticket) {
    $scope.tickets = Ticket;



} ]);
```

I'm sure if have missed something somewhere, but I just don't see it at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: include angular.js instead of angular.min.js to get some more details

Comment: You are loading your app.js before the controllers and services, so it won't know the 'ufyApp.services' and 'ufyApp.controllers' modules. Include your app.js as last

Comment: OMFG. Thanks devqon. how did I miss that? But I still get the error

Comment: Adding regular angular.js taught me i forgot to include the firebase and angularfire js files. I'm gonna hit my head against a wall for an hour